# Remove characters after specific word or sentence

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

character delete works like that :

```
input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("/") + 1);
```

i want to delete after a word or sentence

for example delete [logo] and everything after [logo]

```
   string input= "Test test test    Have a nice day,      [logo]<http://www.example.com/>    John Nash  Software Developer    Google"
```

new input must be like that :

```
string input= "Test test test    Have a nice day,"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `IndexOf`, `Length` and, finally, `Substring` should do:

```
string input = "Test test test    Have a nice day,... ";
string search = "Have a nice day,";

input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(search) + search.Length);
```

**Edit:** If you work with eMail, you may want to test for *several* endings:

```
  string[] finals = new string[] {
    "Have a nice day,",
    "Buy,",
    "yours,"
  };

  int bestIndex = -1;

  foreach (var fin in finals) {
    int index = input.IndexOf(fin);

    if (index >= 0) {
      index += fin.Length;

      if (index > bestIndex) 
        bestIndex = index;
    }
  }

  input = bestIndex < 0 ? input : input.Substring(0, bestIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, i m looking for startings not endings, worked like below for me. It's mainly for ignoring signatures. And of course i will more than one parameter. 
string search = "[logo]";
 input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(search));

Comment: I want to ask you a question too. With my approach, i'm giving parameters to some of general signatures of our customers. Is there any way of removing all of signatures? I redirect all customers mails to a GMAIL adress.  and use S22.Imap for getting e-mails from GMAIL. Can i completely remove signatures from customer e-mails ?

Comment: @Gurum: if I understand you right, you want to remove finals as well: `"Test test test, Have a nice day ... "` should be `"Test test test, "`. If it's your case, just *comment out* `index += fin.Length;` line

Comment: i understand your code, its no problem in there. I want to remove all signatures without using this approach. Is there any possiblity? because i can't predict all keywords what they are going to use. Maybe take mails as HTML files and ignore signature part etc. Have you ever tried like these?

Comment: @Gurum: it depends on what exactly we want to remove. If we have any *pattern* we can try *regular expressions* for this. E.g. let's remove every *single word in brackets* (say, `[logo]`): `input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[[A-Za-z]+\]", "");`

Comment: What if we doesn't have any patterns ? Can't we just reach mails signature part? Is there any way of reaching Gmail signatures  and just delete them?

Comment: @Gurum: In general case, an eMail is a plain text: we don't have any parts there. We can try removing by using patterns (with a help of regular expressions), by dictionaries (if last words is user's name in a dictionary; if we can find a known final, like "yours", "best wishes"). We can combine the approaches: if the very last line contains 1-2 words followed by 1-3 capitalized words (e.g. `Yours, John Smith` or `Best wishes, Margareth`)  we remove it

Answer (score 0):

1. get index of the input words
2. get substring from 0 to index of words of (1)